# Структура службы-windows С#

Tags: c#, winapi, service, windows-service

Здравствуйте. Начал изучать такую область как службы в Visual Studo.

Собственно понял, что они работают "в фоне" не мешая пользователю, а мне это и нужно так как хочу сделать своего рода ЛОГинг определенных папок в Windows, чтобы что-то происходила когда к опредленной папке/фалу захотят получить доступ.

вот что я сделал сначала(работает):

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    private StreamWriter file;

public MyService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ServiceName = "ControlService";
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    file = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("C:\\MyFirstService.log", FileMode.Append));
    this.file.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " - " + "MyFirstService стартовал");
    this.file.Flush();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    this.file.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " - " + "MyFirstService остановлен");
    this.file.Flush();
    this.file.Close();
}
}
```

У меня куча вопросов:
Выше написан код в переопредленных методах СТАРТА и СТОПа службы. 
А где же писать саму логику, те вот тот самый метод, который например на вход берет пути к файлам, которые надо ЛОГировать и следит за ними?

И собственно как следить(повесить слушателя на папку/файл)? слыхал о WinAPI, но что это и где посмотреть и взять не знаю, еще в документации наткнулся на FileSystemWatcher(вроде подходит, но опять же, где описывать его логику(1ый вопрос), чтобы сервис при запуске определял папки, потом уже следил за ними и писал что происходит куда-нибудь).
Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 4):

Если вам нужно периодическое выполнение неких действий, то можете повесить таймер, который будет эти самые действия выполнять с некой периодичностью. Если ваши действия не периодинчы, то можете повесить хук на те или иные события Windows. [Здесь][1] можете посмотреть пример.

Также пару слов о FileSystemWatcher'e. Вот небольшой пример:

```
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
{
    Path = "C:\\SomeDirectory",
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,
};

watcher.Renamed += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("New name is {0} ", e.FullPath); 
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

C его помощью вы можете отслеживать переименования файлов и папок внутри папки C:\SomeDirectory. Также с помощью этого класса можно отслеживать создание, удаление и изменение файлов и папок. А вот насчет открытия папки не уверен. Впрочем, может я и ошибаюсь.

З.Ы. Небольшой совет - не описывайте логику в OnStart и OnStop. Вынесите все в отдельные классы, а в методах сервиса создавайите экземпляры этих классов и вызывайте их методы с последующим освобождением ресурсов
[1]: https://web.archive.org/web/20160316192051/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx